# Using PDO for selecting and deleting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have used some standard code for selecting items from MySQL. How can I change this code using PDOs to make it more secure?

The code below is used to select information.

```
$productssql = "select * from ".databaseconfig."auction_items";
$productssqlrs = $mysqldbobj->mysqldbquery($productssql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from ".databaseconfig."auction_items");
    $sth->execute();

    /* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */

    $productssqlrs = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: How you connect to database? Use pdo syntax to connect with db

Comment: $mysqldbobj = new DatabaseModel;
 $mysqldbcon=$mysqldbobj->mysqldbconnect(MYSQLUSER,MYSQLPASS,MYSQLHOST,MYSQLDBNAME);